# Generate a 3d mesh from a very sparse set of wifi data

Tags: android, android-wifi, google-fusion-tables, triangulation, android-location

I was attempting to map out the signal strength of a wireless network from a very sparse set of data, and was wondering if it was even mathematically possible to do this.

Imagine that we had some application installed on mobile phones, and that each mobile phone was uploading their location and their signal strength to some central database.  The goal would be to take this very sparse graph and attempt to map out the signal strength and then be able to guess at the useful range of the wireless network in two or three dimensions.  I think we should also imagine that no one is standing directly next to the access point, so the center would be unknown.  Very roughly what density of points would we require before we could generate a useful mesh of the wireless network from which to draw a polygon?

You can expect a wireless network strength measured in DBM to scale inversely and linearly with distance.  I was wondering if this could be used to help generate additional points for a Delaunay transformation?

Answer (score 2):

> You can expect a wireless network strength measured in DBM to scale inversely and linearly  with distance

Actually, you can't expect wireless strength to be proportional to distance in any situation outside of an RF test range. Especially indoors, with 2.4G RF you'll have multipath fading and shadow fading to deal with.

a bit of info here.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading

Comment: Interesting reading, thank you.  Considering this new information I wonder if we, given enough points, can infer a general gradient (i.e. increasing and decreasing) to assist with the mapping.  For this application we would not need to know the height of the peaks and valleys, but merely delineate where the useful signal ends.  If we knew that the signal would be stronger in some empty spaces and weaker in other areas we would be closer to figuring out the useful range.  The source signal strength would not need to be exact but the location would need to be coarsely mapped.